# Running cx_Oracle under jython on tomcat

Tags: python, jython, cx-oracle

I'm trying to load cx_Oracle using tomcat.

Loading from python works fine, but for jython I'm getting "module not found". My system.path includes site-packages that contains cx_Oracle.so.

I'm new to jython and I've not had time to familiarize myself with all the variables but I believe I have all the necessary environment variables exported, though clearly something is amiss.

Comment: ok I've gone with zxJDBC. Works well enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ben, not all modules that work with Python in CPython implementation will work on other implementations. If such module use system specific calls, or binds to some .dll/.so file it will not work on other Python implementation. cx_Oracle is one os such modules: it binds to Oracle client (there are cx_Oracle versions for various Oracle versions and various operational systems).

I think you should use JDBC driver if you want to access Oracle from Jython. Then you can use JDBC calls, or use `zxJDBC` Jython module that makes JDBC drivers available via DB API calls. I used both JDBC (with `zxJDBC`) and cx_Oracle in programs that can work from CPython and Jython. To see it in action look to my recipe to [dump Oracle db schema to text](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576534-dump-oracle-db-schema-to-text/?in=user-186902)